# Refrigerator and LED lighting

Tags: refrigerator

My kitchen refrigerator is on a circuit shared with overhead lighting.  I recently replaced the old fluorescent lighting with LED retrofits.  Since then, this branch circuit will sometimes go dead, but the circuit breaker isn't tripped.  When I unplug and then replug the refrigerator, everything works again.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: I would suspect a loose connection in the circuit.  If so you have two worries.  One the loose connection heating up enough to cause a fire, and two the fridge being off for hours and the food going bad.   Turn off the breaker and start checking wire connections for being tight.  If you used the push in connections in back of outlets, change to the screws.

Comment: Until you're able to suss out the problem, I'd install a power failure alarm in the other port on your fridge outlet (assuming it's a duplex outlet).

Comment: Added a _question_ because this is, you know, a _Question_ & Answer site... [tour]

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with LED lighting, but (most likely) everything to do with *"I recently replaced..."* - you've got a loose connection.

So, go over the circuit and check every connection, or at least every connection between the circuit breaker and the refrigerator receptacle. Then again, you could look *particularly* at the **first** connection between the breaker and the things that go dead. But every connection would be best, since one bad connection implies that there might be others.